# React-flexbox-grid: Prop `className` did not match between client and server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-flexbox-grid

When configuring [react-flexbox-grid](https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/) along with sass inside Next.js.
Facing this challenge.

The project created using latest: `create-next-app` and I do not have any custom changes in `.babelrc`

**Error**

> index.js:2178 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server:
>   "col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2" Client: "col-xs-12__flexboxgrid2__AdoKE
>   col-md-4__flexboxgrid2__3pbbS col-lg-2__flexboxgrid2__1x6vt"

Sass Configuration Looks like this:

```
const sassConfig = {
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: '[local]__[name]__[hash:base64:5]'
  }
};
```

Some more:

```
module.exports = withPlugins(
  [[withSass, sassConfig], [withCss], [optimizedImages, optimizedImagesConfig]],
  nextConfiguration
);
```

Tried including and excluding `flexboxgrid` inside sass configuration above, but still no luck.

After long research, I was able to resolve the issue by overriding the `localIdentName:[local]`, so that it matches both client and server render. Unfortunately, if i use: `localIdentName: '[local]__[name]__[hash:base64:5]'`, it fails as the client is using: `localIdentName:[local]`. So, how and where we can override like `clientIdentName`? Do we need to play something with `.babelrc`?